# How to solve this issue failed to show a popup message when not to fill text field/custom radio

Tags: flutter, dart

Step no 6 does not show a popup message but success in saving when clicking the button Save.
[image]

Steps 1-5 show a popup message, can't go to the next step without fill the answer.

[image]

Hi, how to solve this problem? I have separated the questions as per step no. For step no 1-5 when the custom radio or text field is not filled, a popup message will appear telling you the custom text/radio field needs to be filled as I want. But only step no. 6 no pop-up message came out, I can still successfully save even step no. 6 is not filled. What should I do so that step no 6 is the same as steps 1-5. Can anyone help me?

Code:

Code for question step no 6

```
_stepno == 6
                          ? Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                const Text(
                                  "Patient history/examination ",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontSize: 14,
                                      height: 1.5),
                                ),
                                const SizedBox(
                                  height: 5,
                                ),
                                const Text(
                                  "Swollen legs/ankles/feet/face: ",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontSize: 14,
                                      height: 1.5),
                                ),
                                const SizedBox(
                                  height: 5,
                                ),
                                customRadio(
                                    "Yes", "yes", _swollenhistory, "swollen"),
                                if (_swollenhistory == "yes") ...[
                                  const Text(
                                      "If yes, choose swollen body part/s:"),
                                  const SizedBox(height: 5),
                                  textformfieldWithoutLabel(
                                      _swollenbody, 1, true),
                                ],
                                customRadio(
                                    "No", "no", _swollenhistory, "swollen"),
                                const Text(
                                  "Reduce urine output: ",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontSize: 14,
                                      height: 1.5),
                                ),
                                customRadio(
                                    "Yes", "yes", _urineoutput, "urineoutput"),
                                customRadio(
                                    "No", "no", _urineoutput, "urineoutput"),
                                const Text(
                                  "Weakness and fatigue: ",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontSize: 14,
                                      height: 1.5),
                                ),
                                const SizedBox(
                                  height: 5,
                                ),
                                customRadio(
                                    "Yes", "yes", _weakness, "weakness"),
                                customRadio("No", "no", _weakness, "weakness"),
                                const Text(
                                  "Confusion:",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontSize: 14,
                                      height: 1.5),
                                ),
                                const SizedBox(
                                  height: 5,
                                ),
                                customRadio(
                                    "Yes", "yes", _confusion, "confusion"),
                                customRadio(
                                    "No", "no", _confusion, "confusion"),
                                const Text(
                                  "Trouble sleeping: ",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontSize: 14,
                                      height: 1.5),
                                ),
                                const SizedBox(
                                  height: 5,
                                ),
                                customRadio("Yes", "yes", _troublesleep,
                                    "troublesleep"),
                                customRadio(
                                    "No", "no", _troublesleep, "troublesleep"),
                                const Text(
                                  "Foamy/bubble urine: ",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontSize: 14,
                                      height: 1.5),
                                ),
                                const SizedBox(
                                  height: 5,
                                ),
                                customRadio(
                                    "Yes", "yes", _bubbleurine, "bubbleurine"),
                                customRadio(
                                    "No", "no", _bubbleurine, "bubbleurine"),
                                const Text(
                                  "Nausea/vomiting: ",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontSize: 14,
                                      height: 1.5),
                                ),
                                const SizedBox(
                                  height: 5,
                                ),
                                customRadio(
                                    "Yes", "yes", _vomiting, "vomiting"),
                                customRadio("No", "no", _vomiting, "vomiting"),
                                const Text(
                                  "Dry/itchy skin: ",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontSize: 14,
                                      height: 1.5),
                                ),
                                const SizedBox(
                                  height: 5,
                                ),
                                customRadio("Yes", "yes", _dry, "dry"),
                                customRadio("No", "no", _dry, "dry"),
                                const Text(
                                  "Frequent cramps: ",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontSize: 14,
                                      height: 1.5),
                                ),
                                const SizedBox(
                                  height: 5,
                                ),
                                customRadio("Yes", "yes", _cramps, "cramps"),
                                customRadio("No", "no", _cramps, "cramps"),
                                Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [
                                    Expanded(
                                      child: Row(
                                        children: [
                                          const Text(
                                            "Other presenting complaints: ",
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                fontSize: 14,
                                                height: 1.5),
                                          ),
                                          const SizedBox(
                                            width: 5,
                                          ),
                                          Expanded(
                                              child: textformfieldWithoutLabel(
                                                  _complaints, 1, true)),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ],
                            )
                          : const SizedBox(height: 0),
```

Code for Next button

```
const SizedBox(width: 10),
                          _stepno < 6
                              ? Expanded(
                                  child: Container(
                                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15),
                                    child: Center(
                                      child: InkWell(
                                        onTap: () {
                                          if (_stepno < 6) {
                                            _verificationFormfieldAndMoveToNext();
                                          }
                                        },
                                        child: Expanded(
                                          child: Container(
                                            width: double.infinity,
                                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                                left: 20, right: 20),
                                            height: 45,
                                            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                              color: AppConst.primaryColor,
                                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                                Radius.circular(5.0),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                            child: const Center(
                                              child: Text(
                                                "Next",
                                                maxLines: 1,
                                                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                    fontSize: 16,
                                                    color: Colors.white,
                                                    fontWeight:
                                                        FontWeight.w600),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                )
                              : const SizedBox(
                                  width: 0,
                                ),
                          const SizedBox(
                            width: 10,
                          ),
```

Code for Save Button:

```
 _stepno > 5
                              ? Expanded(
                                  child: Container(
                                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15),
                                    child: Center(
                                      child: InkWell(
                                        onTap: () {
                                          _saveInfo(
                                            
                                              );
                                        },
                                        child: Expanded(
                                          child: Container(
                                            width: double.infinity,
                                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                                left: 20, right: 20),
                                            height: 45,
                                            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                              color: AppConst.primaryColor,
                                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                                Radius.circular(5.0),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                            child: const Center(
                                              child: Text(
                                                "Save",
                                                maxLines: 1,
                                                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                    fontSize: 16,
                                                    color: Colors.white,
                                                    fontWeight:
                                                        FontWeight.w600),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                )
                              : const SizedBox(
                                  width: 0,
                                )
```

Code for Next and Save function:

```
_verificationFormfieldAndMoveToNext() async {
        if (_stepno == 1) {
          if (_medicalhistory == "n/a") {
            createToast(_fToast, false, "Please answer question");
            return;
          }
          if (_urineresult == "n/a") {
            createToast(_fToast, false, "Please answer question");
            return;
          }
          if (_medicalhistory == "yes") {
            if (_medicalillness.text.isEmpty) {
              createToast(_fToast, false,
                  "Please share and describe the previous medical illness is empty");
              return;
            }
          }
        }
    
        if (_stepno == 2) {
          if (_surgicalhistory == "n/a") {
            createToast(_fToast, false, "Please answer question");
            return;
          }
          if (_surgicalhistory == "yes") {
            if (_surgicalillness.text.isEmpty) {
              createToast(_fToast, false,
                  "Please share and describe the previous surgical illness");
              return;
            }
          }
        }
    
        if (_stepno == 3) {
          if (_fatherhistory.text.isEmpty) {
            createToast(_fToast, false, "Family history is empty ");
            return;
          }
    
          if (_motherhistory.text.isEmpty) {
            createToast(_fToast, false, "Family history is empty ");
            return;
          }
          if (_dialysis == "n/a") {
            createToast(_fToast, false, "Please answer question");
            return;
          }
        }
    
        if (_stepno == 4) {
          if (_smoke == "n/a") {
            createToast(_fToast, false, "Please answer question");
            return;
          }
          if (_alcohol == "n/a") {
            createToast(_fToast, false, "Please answer question");
            return;
          }
          if (_allergy == "n/a") {
            createToast(_fToast, false, "Please answer question");
            return;
          }
          if (_allergy == "yes") {
            if (_allergichistory.text.isEmpty) {
              createToast(_fToast, false, "Please share the allergic history");
              return;
            }
          }
        }
    
        if (_stepno == 5) {
          if (_medicationhistory == "n/a") {
            createToast(_fToast, false, "Please answer question");
            return;
          }
          if (_usepainkiller == "n/a") {
            createToast(_fToast, false, "Please answer question");
            return;
          }
          if (_usesupplement == "n/a") {
            createToast(_fToast, false, "Please answer question");
            return;
          }
        }
    
        if (_medicationhistory == "yes") {
          if (_medication.text.isEmpty) {
            createToast(_fToast, false,
                "Please share the medications that patient could remember ");
            return;
          }
        }
    
        if (_stepno == 6) {
          if (_swollenhistory == "n/a") {
            createToast(_fToast, false, "Please answer question");
            return;
          }
          if (_urineoutput == "n/a") {
            createToast(_fToast, false, "Please answer question");
            return;
          }
          if (_weakness == "n/a") {
            createToast(_fToast, false, "Please answer question");
            return;
          }
          if (_confusion == "n/a") {
            createToast(_fToast, false, "Please answer question");
            return;
          }
          if (_troublesleep == "n/a") {
            createToast(_fToast, false, "Please answer question");
            return;
          }
          if (_bubbleurine == "n/a") {
            createToast(_fToast, false, "Please answer question");
            return;
          }
          if (_vomiting == "n/a") {
            createToast(_fToast, false, "Please answer question");
            return;
          }
          if (_dry == "n/a") {
            createToast(_fToast, false, "Please answer question");
            return;
          }
          if (_cramps == "n/a") {
            createToast(_fToast, false, "Please answer question");
            return;
          }
          if (_complaints.text.isEmpty) {
            createToast(_fToast, false, "Please answer question");
            return;
          }
          if (_swollenhistory == "yes") {
            if (_swollenbody.text.isEmpty) {
              createToast(_fToast, false, "Please share swollen body part/s");
              return;
            }
          }
    
        }
        _completionPercentage = (_stepno / 100) * 20;
        setState(() {
          _stepno++;
        });
        //customDebugPrint("Steps completed");
      }

    Future<void> _saveInfo() async {
        userInfo = {
          "past_medical_history": _medicalhistory,
          "past_medical_illness": _medicalillness.text,
          "urine_result": _urineresult,
          "past_surgical_history": _surgicalhistory,
          "past_surgical_illness": _surgicalillness.text,
          "family_history_father": _fatherhistory.text,
          "family_history_mother": _motherhistory.text,
          "family_history_dialysis": _dialysis,
          "social_history_smoke": _smoke,
          "social_history_alcohol": _alcohol,
          "social_history_allergy": _allergy,
          "allergic_history": _allergichistory.text,
          "medication_history": _medicationhistory,
          "medication_history_illness": _medication.text,
          "painkiller": _usepainkiller,
          "supplement": _usesupplement,
          "swollen_history": _swollenhistory,
          "swollen_body": _swollenbody.text,
          "urine_output": _urineoutput,
          "weakness": _weakness,
          "confusion": _confusion,
          "trouble_sleep": _troublesleep,
          "bubble_urine": _bubbleurine,
          "vomiting": _vomiting,
          "dry": _dry,
          "cramps": _cramps,
          "other_complaints": _complaints.text
        };
        var result = await ApiRegister().saveInfo(
            userInfo,
            _medicalhistory,
            _medicalillness.text,
            _urineresult,
            _surgicalhistory,
            _surgicalillness.text,
            _fatherhistory.text,
            _motherhistory.text,
            _dialysis,
            _smoke,
            _alcohol,
            _allergy,
            _allergichistory.text,
            _medicationhistory,
            _medication.text,
            _usepainkiller,
            _usesupplement,
            _swollenhistory,
            _swollenbody.text,
            _urineoutput,
            _weakness,
            _confusion,
            _troublesleep,
            _bubbleurine,
            _vomiting,
            _dry,
            _cramps,
            _complaints.text);
        if (result.responseCode == "0") {
          createToast(_fToast, true, "Verification Saved");
        } else {
          createToast(_fToast, false, result.responseMsg);
        }
      }
```